# Where are the Delphi path variables declared?

Tags: delphi, environment-variables, delphi-10.3-rio

After a fresh install of the Delphi 10.3.3 IDE (in a VM), I installed Abbrevia from `GetIt`. Here is the Library Path from the Options dialog:

[image]

Then I searched for the Abbrevia folder in the Windows file-system, but could not find it.

The CatalogRepository-path is here:

**C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\CatalogRepository**

But the Abbrevia folder is NOT in the CatalogRepository directory!

So I wondered where the variables like `$(BDSCatalogRepository)` are DECLARED.

So I looked in `Rapid Environment Editor` and searched for the `BDSCatalogRepository` variable among the system and user environment variables, but could not find it!

I could also neither find the `$(BDS)` variable!

But the Abbrevia components ARE in the Component Palette!

So where are the variables like `$(BDSCatalogRepository)` and `$(BDS)` declared?

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption about the value of `$(BDSCatalogRepository)` is wrong. The path you show is the value for `$(BDSCatalogRepositoryAllUsers)`.

The value for `$(BDSCatalogRepository)` is something like

```
c:\Users\<your_name>\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\CatalogRepository
```

Comment: The path `c:\Users\<your_name>\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\CatalogRepository` does NOT exist! (Of course I have replaced `<your_name>` with my real user name!). Only the directory `C:\Users\<my_name>\Documents` exists, and it does **NOT** contain any `Embarcadero` sub-folder!!

Comment: I have also searched for folders with the name `CatalogRepository`, the only one existing on my system is `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\CatalogRepository`! And there are no other users on this system! For this, it would be important to know where these Delphi path variables are declared!

Comment: I have now created the path `c:\Users\<my_name>\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\CatalogRepository` manually, and then uninstalled and then reinstalled Abbrevia in GetIt, hoping that it would use this manually created directory. But that was not the case! Therefore it would be important to know where these Delphi path variables are declared!

Comment: And, BTW, that was not my assumption. It is written in the list of Library Paths. Look at the above screenshot.

Comment: I have now looked in Tools > Options > IDE > Environment Variables: And I have now found the culprit: The value of `$(BDSCatalogRepository)` is set to `\\Mac\Home\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\CatalogRepository`!!! For this reason, Delphi could not resolve this network path!

Comment: The packages were created by GetIt in this path: `\\Mac\Home\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\CatalogRepository`, but at least the JCL installer had problems installing in this network path!

Answer (score 0):

The Delphi path variables are declared in **Tools** → **Options** → **IDE** → **Environment Variables**:

[image]